# Java : reading all files

Tags: java, file, netbeans, readfile

I am attempting to read in files into a java application running via netbeans.  I have been successful in previewing the files, but I can only preview .txt files.  How can I alter my code to read in any file(s)?  (eg. .doc, .docx, .pdf, .jpg, .png).

```
JFileChooser share = new JFileChooser();
share.showOpenDialog(null);
File f = share.getSelectedFile();
String fileName = f.getAbsolutePath();

    try {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        jTextArea1.read(br, null);
        br.close();
        jTextArea1.requestFocus();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File not found", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Comment: It can't; the native library doesn't support that. You need several other like Apache-POI,etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read them alright ; it's just that they are huge blobs of binary data you can't make any sense of without the appropriate tools. Open one of them with a notepad and you'll get what I'm saying.

Their associated software (Word, Reader, etc...) usually do the decoding, but you may find java libraries that can do as much.

Answer (score 1):

you should use something like apache tika

http://tika.apache.org/

this will allow you to read almost any kind of file

also have a look at java.io.File.list() to find out the types of files you have at a location